# UDP Ping Client - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp, client, udpclient

I am trying to implement a UDP Pinger. In the client code that I wrote, the try statement is not evaluating and just the packet loss message is printing. It is clear that the try statement is not even being hit. I have tried so many different things and nothing has fixed it. Please let me know if you know the issue.
Here is the client code:

```
import random
import time
import sys
from socket import *

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python UDPPingerClient <server ip address> <server port no>")
    exit(0)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
server = (sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
client_socket.settimeout(1)


for i in range(0, 5):

    start_time = time.time()
    host_name = gethostname()
    server_ip = gethostbyname(host_name)
    msg = 'PING ' + str(server_ip) + " " + str(i)

    try:
        client_socket.sendto(msg.encode(), server)
        client_socket.settimeout(1)

        client_socket.recv(1024)
        end_time = time.time()
        rtt = (end_time - start_time) * 1000
        msg += " " + str(format(rtt, '.3f')) + "ms\n"

        print(msg)

    except timeout:
        timeout_msg = 'PING ' + str(server_ip) + " " + str(i + 1) + " " + 'Lost\n'
        print(timeout_msg)
```

This is the server code:

```
import random
import time
import sys
from socket import *

if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
    print("Required arguments: port")
    exit(0)
    
port = int(sys.argv[1])


serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', port))
LOSS_RATE = 0.3
AVERAGE_DELAY = 100 
    
while True:
    rand = random.uniform(0, 1)

    message, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)

    print(message)

    if rand < LOSS_RATE:
       print("Reply not sent.")
       continue

    delay = random.randint(0.0, 2*AVERAGE_DELAY)
    print(delay)
    time.sleep(delay/1000)

    serverSocket.sendto(message, address)
    print("Reply sent.")
```